# Start service at boot and after app has been installed

Tags: android, service

I know you can [start a service on Boot](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/), but how do I start the service after the app has been installed or reinstalled?

I would like to start the service once the app is put on device by Debug/Run of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how do I start the service after
>   the app has been installed or
>   reinstalled?

You do not get control after an install, so you have to start the service through your activity or something.

There's an `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast `Intent` you can monitor for the reinstall scenario, though I have not tried it.

Comment: So I have to start the Service when my main activity is started. That's fine. Now, if the service is running, and if I start it again (when my main activity starts to ensure it started) eventually will fire the start method twice. How do I detect in service if it has been already started and received a second start?

Comment: "Now, if the service is running" -- it isn't running, since you reinstalled the app. "How do I detect in service if it has been already started and received a second start?" -- `boolean` data member would seem to be one possibility, toggled in the service's `onStart()`. You should also be able to use `getRunningServices()` in `ActivityManager` to have the activity only do the manual start if needed, though I have not tried this. You will only run into your problem with an everlasting service (one that tries to run on boot and forever), and I'm not a fan of those.